# Best way for saving information from a program in Java

Tags: java, maven, save

I'm using Maven to write a java program and this program will read information from a .txt file in src->main->resources folder. During the program, the user can modify the information read from the .txt file, and I want to write the updated information to the same .txt file at the end of the program, however, this is where I've run into a problem.

I read that you can't write to a file located inside the resources folder while the jar file is running. So, how would I save information from a program if I can't write to a file located inside the resources folder? Or, is there a way and I just don't know about it?

Keep in mind, I want this program to be usable on any computer, so saving the file on my local disk isn't ideal.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "I want this program to be usable on any computer, so saving the file on my local disk isn't ideal" Isn't saving the data on the local disk of the computer it's running on exactly what you want in this case?

Comment: [Java NIO.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_%28Java%29#JDK_7_and_NIO.2) provides convenient ways to write files across various host OS platforms. Search Stack Overflow to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stream and buffered reader and writer for this purpose

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("example.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("example.txt");
BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
```

when you use this way, you can put the file in the same directory that your jar is, and also when writing it will create the file in the same directory that the jar is